# Price of items that should come in pairs?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, equipment

The [Poisoner's Gloves](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic-items/wondrous-items/wondrous-items/e-g/gloves-poisoner-s) wondrous item(s) cost 5,000 gp. However, I can't find any ruling stating that gloves (or similar items) come in pairs. So, is 5,000 gp the cost of one poisoner's glove?

Answer (score 9):

No, it is the price for a pair (Note that the 2500 price you gave is for crafting the item; buying it is twice that). All magic items that take up a slot take up that entire slot, and all prices are for a complete magic item and cannot be reduced for buying only part of it, unless otherwise specified. Hands is a single slot; the only type of item you can normally have two of is magic rings. That means whether a hands slot magic item is a pair of gloves or a single glove is just flavor; there is no mechanical difference.

The Glove of Storing is an excellent example of how this works:

> This device is a single leather glove[...] A glove of storing uses up the wearer’s entire hands slot. The wearer may not use another item (even another glove of storing) that also uses the hands slot. [Source](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic-items/wondrous-items/wondrous-items/e-g/glove-of-storing).

Comment: Thanks for the price correction. I keep mixing that up. I'll fix it now.  
It matters whether or not I get one or two Poisoner's Gloves because they do not operate collectively.